# Unable to echo out the error messages in an array

Tags: php

I was trying to create an photo upload page. The upload functions well; however when I was trying to trigger some errors, such as not to select any files to update, I can't see the error message; instead, the page turns to blank.

Here is my code (I omitted some properties and methods):

```
Class Photo {
public $errors = array();
public $upload_error = array(

    UPLOAD_ERR_OK           =>"Upload Success.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     =>"The upload file exceeds the upload_max_filesize",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    =>"The upload file exceeds the max file size",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      =>"The upload was only partially uploaded.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      =>"No file was uploaded",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   =>"Missing a temporary folder.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   =>"Failed to write file to disk",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    =>"A PHP extension stopped the file upload."

    );
    public function set_file($file){

    if(empty($file) || !$file || !is_array($file)){
        $this->errors[] = "There was no file uploaded here";
        return false;

    } elseif ($file['error'] !=0){
        $this->errors[] = $this->$upload_error[$file['error']];
        return false;

    } else {

    $this->filename = basename($file['name']);
    $this->tmp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
    $this->photo_type = $file['type'];
    $this->size = $file['size'];

    }

        public function save() {

    if ($this->id) {
        $this->update();

    } else {

        if (!empty($this->errors)) {

            return false;
        }

        if (empty($this->filename) || empty($this->tmp_path)){
            $this->errors[] = "the file was not available!";
        }

        $target_path = SITE_ROOT . DS . 'admin' . DS . $this->upload_directory . DS . $this->filename;


        if (file_exists($target_path)) {
            $this->errors[] = "The file {$this->filename} already existed.";
            return false;
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_path, $target_path)) {

            if ($this->create()) {
                unset($tmp_path);
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "You cannot access the file diretory.";
                return false;
                foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
                    echo $error."<br/>";
                }
            }

        } // if move upload file

    }

} // End Save method

    }
```

The upload page is:

```
    $message = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $photo = new Photo();
    $photo->title = $_POST['title'];
    $photo->set_file($_FILES['file_upload']);

if ($photo->save())

    $message = "Photo upload successfully";

} else {

    $message = join("<br/>", $photo->errors);
}
```

- I can see the success message, "Photo upload successfully", but no error message.

A little bit messy, but could someone help me with this? Thank you!

--UPDATE--

Found a typo in $this->$upload_error[$file['error']]; (should be $this->upload_error), thank you for help! However I can't still see the error messages.

Comment: aw..that was embarrassing, I have looked at it for the whole night. Thanks. The page won't go blank now, but I still can't see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
       else {
            $this->errors[] = "You cannot access the file diretory.";
            return false;
            foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
                echo $error."<br/>";
            }
```

The reason this doesn't work is because you're returning from the method, and then attempting to run the foreach loop. Once you `return` from a method/function, execution inside that method/function ends. Try putting the foreach *before* the `return` statement.